# Uploading/Downloading Multiple Files Concurrently using FTPWebrequest Class

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

I'm trying to send files via FTP very often to remote machines. I have succesfully written all the code for sending/receiving.  Now i want to send different files (ex:3 files) to different IPs (3 Ips).  How to do it?

```
 public bool UploadFile(string file_to_upload,int attempts)
    {


            if (System.IO.File.Exists(file_to_upload))
            {
                    FtpWebResponse response = null;
                    FtpWebRequest ftprequest= null;        
                    int Appendinglength = 0;
                    int TotalLength = 0;
                    pointer = 1;
                    long FTPFilesize = 0;
                    while (--attempts >= 0)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            FileInfo finfo = new FileInfo(file_to_upload);
                            TotalLength = Convert.ToInt32(finfo.Length);

                            ftprequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + IP + "/" + finfo.Name));
                            ftprequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Uname, Pwd);
                            ftprequest.UseBinary = true;
                            ftprequest.Timeout = 500;
                            ftprequest.KeepAlive = false;
                            if (ISFtpFileExists(finfo.Name, out FTPFilesize))
                            {
                                ftprequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                ftprequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                            }

                            //ftprequest.ContentLength = finfo.Length - FTPFilesize;
                            ftprequest.UsePassive = false;
                            fstr = new FileStream(file_to_upload, FileMode.Open);
                            ToWriteStream = ftprequest.GetRequestStream();
                            //response = (FtpWebResponse)ftprequest.GetResponse();
                            attempts = 3000;
                            //fstr.Seek(FTPFilesize, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLength];
                            fstr.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                            startuptime = DateTime.Now;
                            Exoccur("Resuming Upload..");
                            while (pointer != 0)
                            {
                                ToWriteStream.Write(buffer, 0, pointer);
                                Appendinglength += pointer;
                                int prg = CalculateProgress(Appendinglength, TotalLength);
                                PrgUpdate(prg);
                                //lblupdate(prg);
                                pointer = fstr.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                            }
                            ToWriteStream.Close();
                            fstr.Close();
                            break;
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            //ToWriteStream.Close();
                            fstr.Close();
                            if (attempts == 2999)
                            {
                                PrgUpdate(0);
                            }
                            Appendinglength = 0;
                            ftprequest.Abort();
                            ftprequest = null;
                            Thread.Sleep(500);

                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            //attempts = 3000;
                        }
                    }
                    enduptime = DateTime.Now;
                    TimeSpan timetaken = enduptime.Subtract(startuptime);
                    double d = timetaken.TotalMilliseconds;
                    d = d / 1000;
                    Exoccur(Convert.ToString(d));
            }
            else
            {
                Exoccur("File Doesnt occur");

            }
            return true;
    }
```

the above one is for Upload in FTP

```
public bool DownloadFile(string DestPath, string file_to_download)
    {
        PrgUpdate(0);
        FtpWebRequest ftprequest = null;
        int TotalLength = 0;
        WebResponse response = null;
        FileInfo fin = null;
        try
        {
            int Appendinglength = 0;
            if (KeepLength != 0)
            {
                TotalLength = KeepLength;
            }
            else
            {
                //FileStream fst = new FileStream(DestPath, FileMode.Create);
                TotalLength = Convert.ToInt32(GetFileSize_Remotemachine(file_to_download));
            }
            fin = new FileInfo(DestPath);
            //FtpWebRequest ftprequest;
            ftprequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + IP + "/" + file_to_download));
            ftprequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Uname, Pwd);
            ftprequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
            ftprequest.UseBinary = true;
            ftprequest.KeepAlive = false;
            if (fin.Exists)
            {
                ftprequest.ContentOffset = fin.Length;
                fst = new FileStream(DestPath, FileMode.Append);
            }
            else
            {
                fst = new FileStream(DestPath, FileMode.Create);
            }
            response = (WebResponse)ftprequest.GetResponse();
            Stream GetStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLength];
            pointer = GetStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            DateTime starttime = DateTime.Now;
            while (pointer != 0)
            {
                fst.Write(buffer, 0, pointer);
                Appendinglength += pointer;
                PrgUpdate(CalculateProgress(Appendinglength, TotalLength));
                pointer = GetStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            }
            fin  = new FileInfo(DestPath);
            if ((long)TotalLength == fin.Length)
            {
                Exoccur("File download completed.");
            }
            else
            {
                PrgUpdate(100);
            }
            DateTime endtime = DateTime.Now;
            TimeSpan diff = endtime.Subtract(starttime);
            GetStream.Close();
            fst.Close();
            response.Close();
            double d = diff.TotalMilliseconds;
            d = d / 1000;
            KeepLength = 0;
            Exoccur(Convert.ToString(d));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ftprequest.Abort();
            KeepLength = TotalLength;
            PrgUpdate(0);
            Exoccur(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            //response.Close();
            fst.Close();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

and this one is for download

Comment: If you've already written some code, why don't you share that?

Answer (score -3):

i made it work ,we can do different implementations i used threads for doing multiple
uploads concurrently.it works